# Catching Exception in Java

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am writing a JUnit test case for a method. I've written the positive scenario for it but I am not sure if the method is correctly written or designed because I am unable to go into the `Catch` block to catch the exception. I need this for a better branch coverage. I can't use `Mockito` because `DaoException` is a `Checked Exception`.

MUT

```
public List<IUiIntegrationDto> retrieveUiIntegrationReportData(List<String> agencyCode, Integer createdDays, String lob, String transactionStatus, 
        List<String> accounts, String sortKey, String sortOrder) throws ManagerException {
        List<IUiIntegrationDto> intgList = new ArrayList<IUiIntegrationDto>();

        try {
            intgList = getUiIntegrationDao().retrieveUiIntegrationReportData(agencyCode, createdDays, lob, transactionStatus, accounts);
            if (null != intgList) {

                ComparatorUtil.sortESignatureIntegrationFields(intgList, sortKey, sortOrder);
            }
        } catch (DaoException de) {
            String message = "Error retrieving ui integration report data";
            IExceptionHandlerResponse r = getExceptionHandler().handleData(de, ManagerException.class, message);
            if (r.isRethrow()) {
                ManagerException me = (ManagerException) r.getThrowable();
                throw me;
            }

        }
        return intgList;
    }
```

JUnit

```
@Test(expected = DaoException.class)
public void testRetrieveUiIntegrationReportData_Exception() throws Exception {
    List<String> agencyCode = new ArrayList<>();
    agencyCode.add("044494");
    agencyCode.add("044400");

    Integer createdDays = 30;
    String lob = "01";
    String transactionStatus = "Completed";

    List<String> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
    accounts.add("CorpESignClientUser");
    accounts.add("GW_SYS_USER");

    String sortKey = "createdDate";
    String sortOrder = "desc";

    UiIntegrationManager integrationManager = new UiIntegrationManager();

    IUiIntegrationDao integrationDao = Mockito.mock(IUiIntegrationDao.class);

    IUiIntegrationDto uiIntegrationDto = new UiIntegrationDto();
    uiIntegrationDto.setClientUser("CorpESignClientUser");

    List<IUiIntegrationDto> integrationDto = new ArrayList<>();
    integrationDto.add(uiIntegrationDto);

    integrationManager.setUiIntegrationDao(integrationDao);

//  Mockito.doThrow(new DaoException("Exception thrown")).when(integrationDao.retrieveUiIntegrationReportData(agencyCode, createdDays, lob, transactionStatus, accounts));
//  Mockito.when(integrationDao.retrieveUiIntegrationReportData(agencyCode, createdDays, lob, transactionStatus, accounts)).thenReturn(integrationDto);

    integrationDto = integrationManager.retrieveUiIntegrationReportData(agencyCode, createdDays, lob, transactionStatus, accounts, sortKey, sortOrder);

    assertNotNull(integrationDto);
    assertFalse(agencyCode.isEmpty());
    assertEquals(2, agencyCode.size()); 
    assertNotNull(accounts);
    assertEquals("CorpESignClientUser", accounts.get(0));
    assertFalse(integrationDto instanceof ArrayList);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `I can't use Mockito because DaoException is a Checked Exception`? You should be able to make your mock throw any exception...

Comment: Because Mockito only throws RunTimeException.

Comment: I am able to mock it but still it is not going in the Catch block. Mockito.when(integrationManager.getUiIntegrationDao().retrieveUiIntegrationReportData(agencyCode, createdDays, transactionStatus, transactionStatus, accounts)).thenThrow(DaoException.class);

Comment: The correct usage is `.thenThrow(new DaoException(whatever parameters here))`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could turn to the PowerMocking side of things, to "work" on that static call.

My usual recommendation here: if some **static** call is annoying you; then get rid of it.

Simply create an interface denoting the functionality you need; then create a simple implementation that does the static call (to be used in your production environment). In your test environment, you use dependency injection. Meaning: you create a **mocked** instance of that new interface; and you give that to your class under test.

And that's it. All of a sudden you only need EasyMock, to mock a common of garden non-static method call.

And guess what: that also improves your design; because it allows you to fully decouple your client code from that class that contains that static method!